# How to rotate text in Win2D using CanvasControl drawing session?

Tags: windows, uwp, win2d

I'm developing a UWP application using Win2D, and I need to rotate text using the CanvasControl Drawing session. I used `public void DrawText(string text, Vector2 point, Color color)` to render text.

How can I rotate the text to any angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Win2D, rotating text can be achieved by setting `CanvasDrawingSession.Transform`.

```cs
private void CanvasControl_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
    CanvasDrawingSession ds = args.DrawingSession;
    ds.Transform = Matrix3x2.CreateRotation(GetRadians(30));
    ds.DrawText("Hello Win2D!", 10, 10, Colors.Red);
}

private float GetRadians(double angle)
{
    return (float)(Math.PI * angle / 180.0);
}
```

It is worth mentioning that the parameter of `Matrix3x2.CreateRotation` is in radians. If you like to express in angle, you need to convert.

The rotation here is centered on the upper left corner of the canvas, if you need to customize the center of rotation, you can write like this:

```cs
ds.Transform = Matrix3x2.CreateRotation(GetRadians(30),new Vector2(30,30));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It works fine :)

Comment: Could you please help me in this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67996686/how-to-rotate-text-and-align-in-win2d-using-canvascontrol-drawing-session